# Why do pandas and dask perform better when importing from CSV compared to HDF5?

Tags: python, hdf5, dask

I am working with a system that currently operates with large (>5GB) .csv files. To increase performance, I am testing (A) different methods to create dataframes from disk (pandas VS [dask](http://pythondata.com/dask-large-csv-python/)) as well as (B) different ways to store results to disk (.csv VS [hdf5](https://dzone.com/articles/quick-hdf5-pandas) files).

In order to benchmark performance, I did the following:

```
def dask_read_from_hdf():
    results_dd_hdf = dd.read_hdf('store.h5', key='period1', columns = ['Security'])
    analyzed_stocks_dd_hdf =  results_dd_hdf.Security.unique()
    hdf.close()

def pandas_read_from_hdf():
    results_pd_hdf = pd.read_hdf('store.h5', key='period1', columns = ['Security'])
    analyzed_stocks_pd_hdf =  results_pd_hdf.Security.unique()
    hdf.close()

def dask_read_from_csv():
    results_dd_csv = dd.read_csv(results_path, sep = ",", usecols = [0], header = 1, names = ["Security"])
    analyzed_stocks_dd_csv =  results_dd_csv.Security.unique()

def pandas_read_from_csv():
    results_pd_csv = pd.read_csv(results_path, sep = ",", usecols = [0], header = 1, names = ["Security"])
    analyzed_stocks_pd_csv =  results_pd_csv.Security.unique()

print "dask hdf performance"
%timeit dask_read_from_hdf()
gc.collect()
print""
print "pandas hdf performance"
%timeit pandas_read_from_hdf()
gc.collect()
print""
print "dask csv performance"
%timeit dask_read_from_csv()
gc.collect()
print""
print "pandas csv performance"
%timeit pandas_read_from_csv()
gc.collect()
```

My findings are:

```
dask hdf performance
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

pandas hdf performance
1 loop, best of 3: 1.42 s per loop

dask csv performance
1 loop, best of 3: 7.88 ms per loop

pandas csv performance
1 loop, best of 3: 827 ms per loop
```

When hdf5 storage can be accessed faster than .csv, and when dask creates dataframes faster than pandas, why is dask from hdf5 slower than dask from csv? Am I doing something wrong?

**When does it make sense for performance to create dask dataframes from HDF5 storage objects?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HDF5 is most efficient when working with numerical data, I'm guessing you are reading a single string column, which is its weakpoint.

Performance of string data with HDF5 can be dramatically improved by using a `Categorical` to store your strings, assuming relatively low cardinality (high number of repeated values)

It's from a little while back, but a good blog post here going through exactly these considerations.
http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization

You may also look at using parquet - it is similar to HDF5 in that it is a binary format, but is column oriented, so a single column selection like this will likely be faster.

Recently (2016-2017) there has been significant work to implement a fast native reader of parquet->pandas, and the next major release of pandas (`0.21`) will have `to_parquet` and `pd.read_parquet` functions built in.

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://matthewrocklin.com/blog//work/2017/06/28/use-parquet