# How to append new categories to HDF5 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, categories, hdf5

> **Answered**: It appears that this datatype will not be suited for adding
>   arbitrary strings into hdf5store.

**Background**

I work with a script which generates single rows of results and appends them to a file on disk in an iterative approach. To speed things up, I decided to use HDF5 containers rather than .csv. [A benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45993751/6060083) then revealed that strings slow HDF5 down. I was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998153/6060083) this can be mitigated when converting strings to `categorical` dtype.

**Issue**

I have not been able to append categorical rows *with new categories* to HDF5. Also, I don't know how to control the dtypes of `cat.codes`, which AFAIK can be done somehow.

## Reproducible example:

**1 - Create large dataframe with categorical data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import HDFStore, DataFrame
import random, string

dummy_data = [''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 5)) for i in range(100000)]
df_big = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, columns = ['Dummy_Data'])
df_big['Dummy_Data'] = df_big['Dummy_Data'].astype('category')
```

**2 - Create one row to append**

```
df_small = pd.DataFrame(['New_category'], columns = ['Dummy_Data'])
df_small['Dummy_Data'] = df_small['Dummy_Data'].astype('category')
```

**3 - Save (1) to HDF and try to append (2)**

```
df_big.to_hdf('h5_file.h5', \
      'symbols_dict', format = "table", data_columns = True, append = False, \
       complevel = 9, complib ='blosc')

df_small.to_hdf('h5_file.h5', \
      'symbols_dict', format = "table", data_columns = True, append = True, \
       complevel = 9, complib ='blosc')
```

**This results in the following Exception**

> ValueError: invalid combinate of [values_axes] on appending data [name->Dummy_Data,cname->Dummy_Data,dtype->int8,kind->integer,shape->(1,)]
>   vs current table
>   [name->Dummy_Data,cname->Dummy_Data,dtype->int32,kind->integer,shape->None]

**My fixing attempts**

I tried to adjust the dtypes of `cat.catcodes`:

```
df_big['Dummy_Data'] = df_big['Dummy_Data'].cat.codes.astype('int32')
df_small['Dummy_Data'] = df_small['Dummy_Data'].cat.codes.astype('int32')
```

When I do this, the error disappears, but so does the categorical dtype:

```
df_test = pd.read_hdf('h5_file.h5', key='symbols_dict')
print df_mydict.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100001 entries, 0 to 0       # The appending worked now
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Dummy_Data    100001 non-null int32      # Categorical dtype gone
dtypes: int32(1)                         # I need to change dtype of cat.codes of categorical    
memory usage: 1.1 MB                     # Not of categorical itself
```

In addition, `df_small.info()` does not show the dtype of `cat.codes` in the first place, which makes it difficult to debug. What am I doing wrong?

**Questions**

**1. How to properly change dtypes of `cat.codes`?

 2. How to properly append Categorical Data to HDF5 in python?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054761/4893407 for comments on categoricals in HDF with pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, but as far as I looked at least at h5py module, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html , HDF5 supports Numpy datatypes, which do not include any categorical datatype.

Same for [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/datatypes.html), which is used by Pandas.

*Categories* datatype is introduced and used in [Pandas datatypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), and is described:

> A categorical variable takes on a *limited*, and *usually fixed*, number of possible values (categories; levels in R)

So what might be happening is perhaps every time in order to add a new category, you have to somehow re-read all existing categories from hdf5store in order for Pandas to reindex it?

From the docs in general, however, it appears that this datatype will **not** be suited for adding arbitrary strings into hdf5store, unless you are sure after maybe a couple of additions there will be no new categories.

As additional note, unless your application demands extremely high performance, storing data in SQL might potentially be a better option -- SQL has better support for strings, for one thing. For example, while SQLite was found slower than HDF5 in some [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628329/hdf5-concurrency-compression-i-o-performance), they didn't include processing strings. Jumping from CSV to HDF5 sounds like jumping from a horsecart to a rocket, but perhaps a car or airplane would work just as well (or better, as it has more options, to stretch the analogy)?

Comment: Actually the readout of all present categories from hdf5 to pandas, followed by subsequent concatenation, followed by overwriting the hdf5 store was a temporary workaround. This comes to its limits of course as soon as the store is bigger than RAM. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @sudonym this seems to support the view that all categories in pandas have to be known beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

if it is helpfull for you, I will rewrite the beginning of your code. It works for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore, DataFrame
import random, string


def create_dummy(nb_iteration):

    dummy_data = [''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 5)) for i in range(nb_iteration)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, columns = ['Dummy_Data'])

    return df

df_small= create_dummy(53)
df_big= create_dummy(100000)

df_big.to_hdf('h5_file.h5', \
  'symbols_dict', format = "table", data_columns = True, append = False, \
  complevel = 9, complib ='blosc')

df_small.to_hdf('h5_file.h5', \
  'symbols_dict', format = "table", data_columns = True, append = True, \
  complevel = 9, complib ='blosc')

df_test = pd.read_hdf('test_def.h5', key='table')
df_test
```

Comment: This works because the categories in your df_small are not new - add 1 six letter string to df_small and you will see

Comment: that being said, df_small is one row only. If you add more than 128 rows, the dtype of cat.codes will change to int32 and it will work - however, the question is about adding new categories (only)